# Pushing updated heroku app from local project to heroku master, redis

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, redis, backend

I need to manually update changes to my heroku master app after deployment from my local project without getting rid of any data that was already there in my last instance. How can I do this (on windows or ubuntu on windows). Thanks!

Comment: Deployments don't get rid of Redis data. They get rid of any temporary files on the dyno's filesystems, but that goes away at least once daily anyways. Can you elaborate on the nature of this data and why you think a deployment will remove it?

Comment: Hi, before I answer that question, the objective is to update the existing master app. Now the nature of this app is a crypto currency blockchain. Every wallet has its own app with the root address of the main heroku app. One thing I have noticed is that once every like 2 hours, the balance of every app instance gets wiped and so does the block-chain. So if it's not bothering you I actually need expertise in two things, but let's first focus on updating the existing root app

Comment: You need to read https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted. You can't use the filesystem for persistent data. Period.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, Thank you for your help! Although, if u can recommend some other way to achieve what I am doing I will greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Sure. Host it pretty much anywhere that isn't Heroku, where your filesystem will live longer than 24 hours.

Comment: any recommendations for already configured servers? I am not well when it comes to configuring my own servers, let alone server sided development I am not so well at.